# Battery door switch on 1100D broke, any way to fix it?

Tags: canon-1100d

Yesterday, a tiny plastic part broke off the microswitch on the inside of my camera's body, turning it into a fancy paperweight. Why Canon would would make the singular most important part of the camera out of not-even-a-millimeter-thick plastic is beyond me.

My question is: Is there any way to override said switch? I have never needed the functionality the switch provided and I don't plan on starting now.

Comment: What was the switch for? Can you post an image?

Comment: I wanted to confirm that the part that broke off is on the camera side and not the door side. The door can be replaced fairly easily...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the switch was for checking whether the battery door is closed or not. Also, the part was inside the camera and not on the door. I thought the initial question made that very clear.

Comment: Seems like a rant about the design of the camera battery compartment.  If you feel the camera is worth saving, take it someplace for repair.

Comment: @PeterW. Given the questions in the comment the initial question did not make it very clear. Could you post a photo of the broken part? Perhaps someone can come up with an idea to override it when it's clear what is broken.

Comment: I asked the question because from the pictures of the door it seemed that the door had a protruding part that pressed onto a recessed button in the camera body. I couldn't reconcile your description with the pictures I saw.

Answer (score 3):

I would take your camera to an independent camera repair shop to see if they can disable that switch to leave it in the "on" position.

Canon would never repair it that way but it could be a simple fix.

Here is a photo of the battery door micro-switch in my SL1. Is this what your switch looks like?
[image]